# How to use createTextNode with JSDOM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am trying to write a UI test for a HTML component using Jasmine and jsdom.
In my component I am using `createTextNode` to generate the content of the DOM element.

However when the test runs the `document.createTextNode` is returning an empty object

```js
let dom = new JSDOM("<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>");
    global.window = dom.window;
    global.document = dom.window.document;
    global.navigator = global.window.navigator;

    let div = document.createElement("div");
    let content = document.createTextNode("hello");
    console.log(content); //  Text {}
    div.appendChild(content);
    console.log(div.innerText) // undefined
```

Comment: Somebody really didn't like this question or the answers for some reason, lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage is fine, your issue is here:

```
console.log(div.innerText) // undefined
```

`innerText` isn't implemented in JSDOM, so you're seeing `undefined` as your result. You'll need to use `textContent` or `innerHTML` to check the text instead:

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

let dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html>'), doc = dom.window.document;

let text = doc.createTextNode('here is some text');

let div = doc.createElement('div');
div.appendChild(doc.createElement('span')); // just for example
div.appendChild(text);
div.appendChild(doc.createElement('span')); // just for example

console.log('innerText:', div.innerText);   // not implemented in JSDOM
console.log('textContent:', div.textContent); // this'll work
console.log('innerHTML:', div.innerHTML);   // as will this

doc.body.appendChild(div);
console.log('full document:');
console.log(dom.serialize());
```

This will output:

```
innerText: undefined
textContent: here is some text
innerHTML: <span></span>here is some text<span></span>
full document:
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><div><span></span>here is some text<span></span></div></body></html>
```

(See https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1245 and the various linked issues therein.)

Comment: `let dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html>'), doc = dom.window.document;`
my eyes